# Limit of convolution

Tags: real-analysis

I am in a difficult situation with this question.

**Question** Let $F_1,F_2:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ be continuous functions and $p$ be positive real number. Consider the convolution function order $p$ of $F_1$ and $F_2$
$$
(F_1*_pF_2)(x)=\left\{\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(F_1(y)F_2(x-y)\right)^pdy\right\}^{\frac{1}{p}}
$$
Find the conditions on $F_1, F_2$ such that
$$
\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty}(F_1*_pF_2)(x)=\sup_{y\in\mathbb{R}}F_1(y)F_2(x-y)
$$
Thank you for all hints and solutions.

Comment: You need some integrability assumption on $F_1$ and $F_2$. Try taking two constant functions to see that it won't work. (Moreover, you should explicitly point out that both functions are nonnegative)

Comment: Thanks Giuseppe Negro. I revised my question as your suggestion.

Comment: It seams to me that the question has a little to do with convolution. It just asks whether norm $\|\cdot \|_p$ converges to $\|\cdot \|_\infty$ as $p$ goes to infinity.